Toilet backed up
I poured Liquid Plumber in my bathroom sink, and now my toilet is backed up. It was working fine before I put it in the sink.

Why did you use it in the sink?  Was the sink blocked?  Drain pipes are connected together, the blockage might just have moved lower, blocking the toilet also.  A plumbers snake might be useful.

I poured the liquid plummer in the bathroom sink because when I ran the water in the sink it would bubble up in the toilet. Rebecca Ledee

Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Be sure to log in as the same user so you can revise your question with critical detail. It doesn't belong in comments.

Your question doesn't give a lot of info to go on, but I don't think Liquid Plumber will cause a blockage. More likely, your toilet and sink are both blocked up for the same reason, and the problem is deep in the drain. Or maybe the liquid plumber partly dissolved the clog, and let it move farther down where it re-clogged and is blocking both.
Either way, it sounds like you need to call a rooter service. If you want to DIY this, look into obtaining and learning how to use a drain snake.
Also just FYI, products like liquid plumber are tempting for a quick fix, but can sometimes damage your plumbing - especially if used often.

I don't know, based on what you've said, but I think you should hire a plumber. Said plumber would come with all the tools and parts to fix your problem with him/her. In one occasion I remember, I told the arriving plumber, "Boy are we glad to see you.>
